# UWP: How to increase the price for an Add-on in Microsoft Store

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-dev-center

I was trying to increase the base price for a subscription Addon that I have in my UWP application and I wasn't able to do that.
In the dropdown list my selected price is the last one and I can't select anything higher.

[image]

I tried also to use a Free-Form Price for specific markets but I got this error: `Your subscription price can’t be increased. Please choose a price that is lower or equal to the price in your previous submission.`

It seams a bit strange that you can't schedule a price change (increase) for your Add-on. What's the reason for blocking a price increase?

I could create another Add-on but the solutions it's not ideal for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seams a bit strange that you can't schedule a price change (increase) for your Add-on. What's the reason for blocking a price increase?

According to the `Important` note in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app#steps-to-enable-a-subscription-add-on-for-your-app), you cannot increase the price after publishing the add-on:

> By default, when you create any add-on the price is initially set to **Free**. Because you cannot raise the price of a subscription add-on after you complete the add-on submission, be sure to choose the price of your subscription here.

Thus, you might create a new add-on with the price you want. If you have any suggestion on the subscription add-on product, you could give your feedback **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app#related-topics)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zhendong! I will definitely fill in the feedback form.